# Why is my Bootstrap div Alignment not working?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, web-development-server, portfolio

I have been trying to make a portfolio website for myself.
But for 'My works' div when I apply the Bootstrap class, I am not getting the result as I am expected to get. The alignment of the div is not in a grid.

Here's how it shows up:

[image]

I am not able to fix this problem.

The HTML code:

```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="Responsive Portfolio Template">
  <meta name="author" content="Suvrat Jain">
  <title>Responsive Bootstrap Template for Portfolio</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="menu">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid splash" id="splash">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/71/9e/59/719e59481d2be40a77ab6c3386fc0a45--photoshop-illustrator-illustrator-tutorials.jpg" alt="Portrait of Mr. Roboto" class="profile-image">
      <h1>HELLO!</h1>
      <h1 class="intro-text"><span class="lead" id="typed">I am a </span></h1>
      <span class="continue"><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- About Section -->
  <section class="success" id="about">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
          <h2>About Me</h2>
          <hr class="star-light">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2">
          <p class="content-text" style="text-align:justify;">Hey there! I am a junior software developer based in Mumbai, India. I work with some of the popular front end technologies to create beautiful websites that get noticed. I seek experience to gain more knowledge in the web development field.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <p class="content-text">If you are in need of a beautiful simple website, I'm your guy. I look forward to talking to you soon!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center contact-button">
          <a href="#contact" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact Me
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <div class="container-fluid portfolio-container-holder content-section" id="portfolio">
        <div class="portfolio-container container">
            <h1 class="text-center">My Portfolio</h1>
      <hr class="star-portfolio">
            <div class="row">
                
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-11 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/QFX1CKL/8705c160752271.png" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Quantum Computing and cryptocurrency</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-11 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/GVr9drm/illu-app-modernization-whtbg.png" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Logistic Regression in Machine Learning</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-11 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/nwzg94P/0-Yb-Vi-GAYNXI51ek-E.png" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Introduction to Computer Vision</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-11 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5vNfRC9/depositphotos-1245773-stock-photo-simple-math-example.png" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Addition of Two Numbers in Python</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-11 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/GVr9drm/illu-app-modernization-whtbg.png" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Logistic Regression in Machine Learning</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-11 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/nwzg94P/0-Yb-Vi-GAYNXI51ek-E.png" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>AI: myths versus reality</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-11 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/nwzg94P/0-Yb-Vi-GAYNXI51ek-E.png" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Introduction to Computer Vision</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-11 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/nwzg94P/0-Yb-Vi-GAYNXI51ek-E.png" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Introduction to Computer Vision</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
  <!-- Contact form -->
  <div class="container-fluid contact-me-container content-section" id="contact">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="intro-text text-center">Contact Me</h1>
      <hr class="star-light">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email ID">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-default submit-button btn-lg btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Send</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer>
    <div class="container footer-container">
      <div class="row footer-row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 text-center">
          <h4 class="text-center">Find me here</h4>
          <address> <strong><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i> Monsters Inc.</strong><br>Lorem ipsum dolor, sir amet,<br>Aurangabad, India 431001<br><br><a class="tel" href="tel:9999988888" type="tel"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i><span> +91 </span></a></address>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 social-section">
          <div class="text-center">
            <h4 class="text-center">Also, I can be found here</h4>
            <div class="text-center social-buttons">

              <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/simplysuvi" class="btn btn-default btn-lg social-button link-linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="https://instagram.com/simplysuvi" class="btn btn-default btn-lg social-button link-instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
            <hr class="footer-hr">
            <h4 class="author">Made with <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> by <strong>Akshra Dube</strong></h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with columns used for a single row.
Note that, each row can have only 12 columns. But you are using multiple columns  in a single row. so it doesn't work like that.

Refer this more details - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

You can try enclosing two cards per each row (assuming you wanted to show twoo cards per row). see below code. Hope this helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="Responsive Portfolio Template">
  <meta name="author" content="Suvrat Jain">
  <title>Responsive Bootstrap Template for Portfolio</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="menu">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid splash" id="splash">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/71/9e/59/719e59481d2be40a77ab6c3386fc0a45--photoshop-illustrator-illustrator-tutorials.jpg" alt="Portrait of Mr. Roboto" class="profile-image">
      <h1>HELLO!</h1>
      <h1 class="intro-text"><span class="lead" id="typed">I am a </span></h1>
      <span class="continue"><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- About Section -->
  <section class="success" id="about">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
          <h2>About Me</h2>
          <hr class="star-light">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2">
          <p class="content-text" style="text-align:justify;">Hey there! I am a junior software developer based in Mumbai, India. I work with some of the popular front end technologies to create beautiful websites that get noticed. I seek experience to gain more knowledge in the web development field.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <p class="content-text">If you are in need of a beautiful simple website, I'm your guy. I look forward to talking to you soon!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center contact-button">
          <a href="#contact" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact Me
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <div class="container-fluid portfolio-container-holder content-section" id="portfolio">
        <div class="portfolio-container container">
            <h1 class="text-center">My Portfolio</h1>
      <hr class="star-portfolio">
            <div class="row">
                
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-11 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/QFX1CKL/8705c160752271.png" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Quantum Computing and cryptocurrency</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-11 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/GVr9drm/illu-app-modernization-whtbg.png" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Logistic Regression in Machine Learning</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-11 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/nwzg94P/0-Yb-Vi-GAYNXI51ek-E.png" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Introduction to Computer Vision</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-11 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5vNfRC9/depositphotos-1245773-stock-photo-simple-math-example.png" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Addition of Two Numbers in Python</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                 </div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-11 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/GVr9drm/illu-app-modernization-whtbg.png" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Logistic Regression in Machine Learning</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-11 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/nwzg94P/0-Yb-Vi-GAYNXI51ek-E.png" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>AI: myths versus reality</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                 </div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-11 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/nwzg94P/0-Yb-Vi-GAYNXI51ek-E.png" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Introduction to Computer Vision</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-11 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/nwzg94P/0-Yb-Vi-GAYNXI51ek-E.png" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Introduction to Computer Vision</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
         </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
  <!-- Contact form -->
  <div class="container-fluid contact-me-container content-section" id="contact">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="intro-text text-center">Contact Me</h1>
      <hr class="star-light">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email ID">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-default submit-button btn-lg btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Send</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer>
    <div class="container footer-container">
      <div class="row footer-row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 text-center">
          <h4 class="text-center">Find me here</h4>
          <address> <strong><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i> Monsters Inc.</strong><br>Lorem ipsum dolor, sir amet,<br>Aurangabad, India 431001<br><br><a class="tel" href="tel:9999988888" type="tel"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i><span> +91 </span></a></address>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 social-section">
          <div class="text-center">
            <h4 class="text-center">Also, I can be found here</h4>
            <div class="text-center social-buttons">

              <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/simplysuvi" class="btn btn-default btn-lg social-button link-linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="https://instagram.com/simplysuvi" class="btn btn-default btn-lg social-button link-instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
            <hr class="footer-hr">
            <h4 class="author">Made with <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> by <strong>Akshra Dube</strong></h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have tried to do it but its of no use.... Several blocks are stills being empty.... Here is the img- https://ibb.co/YRjWYnG